# Subtitle Project: How to solve the unicode reading failure?

Tags: python, unicode

Basically I'm doing a subtitle project.
Very complicated, but I just want to insert lines after a line for all lines in a converted ASS file(Currently still a txt file in the experiment)

[Untouched lines. I won't talk about Aegisub problems here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O689z.jpg)

> Dialogue: 0,0:00:00.00,0:00:03.90,Default,,0,0,0,,Hello, viewers. This is The Reassembler,
>
> Dialogue: 0,0:00:03.90,0:00:07.04,Default,,0,0,0,,the show where we take everyday objects in their component form
>
> Dialogue: 0,0:00:07.04,0:00:10.24,Default,,0,0,0,,and put them back together, very slowly.

Objective:
Every line in the dialogue section appended with
`'\N{\3c&HAA0603&\fs31\b1}'`

[image: Modified lines, still Aegisub stuff]

> Dialogue: 0,0:00:00.00,0:00:03.90,Default,,0,0,0,,Hello, viewers. This is The Reassembler,\N{\3c&HAA0603&\fs31\b1}
>
> Dialogue: 0,0:00:03.90,0:00:07.04,Default,,0,0,0,,the show where we take everyday objects in their component form\N{\3c&HAA0603&\fs31\b1}
>
> Dialogue: 0,0:00:07.04,0:00:10.24,Default,,0,0,0,,and put them back together, very slowly.\N{\3c&HAA0603&\fs31\b1}

The Python 3.x code:

```
text1 = open('d:\Programs\sub1.txt','r')
text2 = open('e:\modsub.ass','w+')

alltext1 = text1.read()
lines = alltext1.split('\n')
for i in range(lines.index('[Events]')+1,len(lines)):
    lines[i] += '    hello    '
print(lines)
text2.write(str(lines))
text1.close()
text2.close()
```

1.Python doesn't recognize one or two characters in it, apparently, in unicode

```
 '\N{\3c&HAA0603&\fs31\b1}'
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-23: unknown Unicode character name
```

How to deal with it without affecting the output?

2.When I used '    hello    ' instead of the subtitling code, the output was this:

> 'Dialogue: 0,0:00:07.04,0:00:10.24,Default,,0,0,0,,and put them back together, very slowly.    hello    ', 'Dialogue: 0,0:00:10.24,0:00:11.72,Default,,0,0,0,,That feels very nice.    hello    ', 'Dialogue: 0,0:00:11.72,0:00:13.36,Default,,0,0,0,,Oh, yes. Look at that!    hello    ',

et cetera, instead of lines after lines arrangement.
How to make the strings just line up and take out the quotes and stuff?

Comment: I don't see anything in this code that would use the `unicodeescape` codec. Are you sure you're sharing all the code?

Comment: @MarkRansom The string literal `'\N{\3c&HAA0603&\fs31\b1}'` raises that error because it is an invalid unicode-name escape. In any case the Op probably replaced it with the `'   hello  '` thing, thus making debugging the problem harder than it ought to be.

Comment: @Bakuriu thanks for that, it led me straight to the solution. It never occurred to me that the Python interpreter itself was trying to decode the string literal!

Comment: I think my program is completely wasted. Fully functional for most .ass subs when I was working on Aegisub, until I tried to convert my video with the sub, which resulted in a conversion failure.

Answer (score 0):

Use a raw string literal, i.e. replace:

```
'\N{\3c&HAA0603&\fs31\b1}'
```

with:

```
r'\N{\3c&HAA0603&\fs31\b1}'
```

In this way the interpreter will not try to look for the unicode character named `\3c&HAA0603&\fs31\b1` which does not exist.

---

```
>>> '\N{\3c&HAA0603&\fs31\b1}'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-23: unknown Unicode character name
>>> r'\N{\3c&HAA0603&\fs31\b1}'
'\\N{\\3c&HAA0603&\\fs31\\b1}'
>>> print(r'\N{\3c&HAA0603&\fs31\b1}')
\N{\3c&HAA0603&\fs31\b1}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using a string with `\` characters in it, without escaping them. You need to double them up or use the `r''` notation.

```
lines[i] += '\\N{\\3c&HAA0603&\\fs31\\b1}'
```

or

```
lines[i] += r'\N{\3c&HAA0603&\fs31\b1}'
```

As for your other problem, you're writing `str(lines)` which shows a literal representation. Use `'\n'.join(lines) + '\n'` instead.